# How to implement authorization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization

Suppose, I have a model called Animal. This model contains enum attribute with two possible states.

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum kind: [ :cat, :dog ]
end
```

Then in my controller I create different instance variables.

```
class AnimalsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @cats = Animal.cat
    @dogs = Animal.dog
  end
end
```

In my view I got two separate collections.

```
<h1>Animals</h1>

<%= render partial: 'animals/cat', collection: @cats, as: :cat %>
<%= render partial: 'animals/dog', collection: @dogs, as: :dog %>
```

How can I make an authorization to be able to edit the first collection's resources and not to be able to edit the second ones?

The following approach won't work because it works only for one action entirely.

```
before_action :current_user_only, except: [:edit]
```

So, how do I implement that kind of authorization?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to authorize a user to edit *all* the `cat` records, but not `dog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorization - in any capacity - is typically denoted by two patterns:

- `record/object` based
- `role/user` based

What you seem to need is `record/object` based authorization; whereby a user can edit an object if it matches certain criteria.

The most efficient way to do this in Rails is with a gem called [`Pundit`](https://github.com/elabs/pundit), although I prefer [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) (originally [`CanCan`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)):

```
#Gemfile 
gem "pundit"

#app/policies/animal.rb
class AnimalPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :animal

  def initialize(user, animal)
    @user   = user
    @animal = animal
  end

  def edit?
    animal.cat?
  end

  def update?
    animal.cat?
  end
end

#app/controllers/animals_controller.rb
class AnimalsController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @animal = Animal.find params[:id]
      authorize @animal
   end

   def update
      @animal = Animal.find params[:id]
      authorize @animal
   end
end
```

You can then validate on the front-end:

```
<% if policy(animal).update? %>
   <%= link_to "Edit", animal %>
<% end %>
```

--

This gives you the ability to allow the user to perform whichever actions you deem appropriate.

---

**Update**

Since you wish to evaluate users as well as objects, you're quite fortunate that both `Pundit` and `CanCanCan` support `users` by default:

```
#app/policies/animal.rb
class AnimalPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :animal

  def initialize(user, animal)
    @user   = user
    @animal = animal
  end

  def edit?
    user.moderator? && animal.cat?
  end

  def update?
    user.moderator? && animal.cat?
  end
end
```

The ultimate point to remember is that authorization is a boolean pattern - `unless true deny access`. This means that you just have to provide the conditional logic in your authorization systems (as above), to return either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: What if my **User** model has different roles and I'd like to give different permissions to them?

Comment: You'll be able to pull it off with Pundit or CanCanCan, just need some validation in the policy/ability definitions. `user.admin?` for example

Comment: If you give me context, I'll be able to write an update

Comment: I have **User** model with enum attribute `enum role: [:user, :moderator]`. And I would like moderator to be able to edit cats and not be able to edit  dogs. However, user cannot edit anything whatsoever. He can only view all resources.

Comment: Okay let me write an update for you, thanks for posting a response

Comment: Great! Now I seem to be able to understand how things work.

Comment: Now go forth and create! For England!!